# Convert integer to zero-padded binary string

Tags: java, binary

when converting int to binary, how to output it to 8 character, currently it only display 1 and short of the 7 zeros

### code

```
int x = 1;
String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
System.Out.Println(bin);
```

example output to 0000 0001

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you mean but how about something like

```
String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(1)).replace(' ', '0')
```

will generate `00000001`

Answer (score 1):

You can pad your binary string with zeroes.

```
String bin = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(x).replace(' ', '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert, check the resulting length and add zeros if < 8.