# How with Integer.toBinaryString can I set the amount of digits in java?

Tags: java, digits

I have these two lines of code that I need to modify so that they will always return four digits of binary.

```
    String binary1 = Integer.toBinaryString(t1);
    String binary2 = Integer.toBinaryString(t2);

    String first1 = binary1.substring(0,0);
    String first2 = binary2.substring(0,0);
    String second1 = binary1.substring(1,1);
    String second2 = binary2.substring(1,1);
    String third1 = binary1.substring(2,2);
    String third2 = binary2.substring(3,3);
    String fourth1 = binary1.substring(4,4);
    String fourth2 = binary2.substring(4,4);
```

Is there a method that cn controll the amount of digits in binary1 and binary2

P.S. T1 and T2 are two user-subitted imputs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java integer to binary string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856626/java-integer-to-binary-string)

Answer (score 4):

The Javadoc for [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) says (in part),

> This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) with no extra leading `0`s.

So, no. You cannot control the number of digits with `toBinaryString(int)`. You might use [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) like

```
String binary1 = String.format("%4s", Integer.toString(t1, 2))
    .replace(' ', '0');
String binary2 = String.format("%4s", Integer.toString(t2, 2))
    .replace(' ', '0');
```