# Java: Right shifting the number 1 does not work

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am trying to shift the number 1 to the right.

So originally, the bit mask should be:

```
1
```

Then, the bit mask should be:

```
01
```

Below is my code:

```
int bitmask = 1;
bitmask >>= 1;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bitmask));
```

The output however, is just:

```
0
```

Comment: `1` and `01` are the exact same number, just like in decimals. When you shift to the right, the right most bit is shifted out of the binary number, so it disappears.

Comment: But shifting right by 1 has the same effect as dividing by 2. Integer division discards fractions, so 1/2 is zero int.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we are misunderstanding about how bitshifting works. When doing a right shift, the least significant bit (1) is lost.

1 in binary is 0b01 already. This is equivalent with 0b00000001. Shifting this right results in 0b00.

Try this instead and see that bitshifting works.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int bitmask = 0b10;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bitmask));
        bitmask >>= 1;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bitmask));
    }
}
```

Output

```
10
1
```

Answer (score 1):

The bitmask `1` and `01` or `001` or `0...1` are all the same. When you do a right shift the least significant digit (1 in your case) is lost, so the output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bitmask = 1;
    bitmask >>= 1;
    int binaryval = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(bitmask));
    String binary = String.format("%2s", Integer.toString(1, 2)).replace(' ', '0');
    System.out.println(binary);
}
```

The Javadoc for Integer.toBinaryString(int) says (in part),

This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) with no extra leading 0s. Reference is made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528171/how-with-integer-tobinarystring-can-i-set-the-amount-of-digits-in-java)