# How to encode N strings to binary numbers with minimum number of digits

Tags: java

I have a list of names, `ArrayList<String> names`. For example:

```
ArrayList<String> names= new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("foo1"); 
names.add("foo2");
names.add("foo3");
names.add("foo4");
names.add("foo5");
```

Then I can encode these five names into binary numbers with (ceiling(log(5))=) 3 digits: `foo1=000, foo2=001, foo3=010, foo4=011, foo5=100`. I want a function which looks like `public int[] return_binary_encoding(String name, ArrayList<String> names)` , where `name` is in `names`.

Comment: So you want a number tied to the string... For your system all data is in binary, so your 000, 001, 010, 011, 100 are literally 0, 1, 2, 3, 4... Isn't that the index value of your strings in the ArrayList?

Comment: What is `String name`? What is its significance in the question you asked? Have you tried anything - some lines of code?

Comment: `name` is in the `names`. Ok, now I feel this was a stupid question since I can get the index of `name` by `names.indexOf(name)` and then I just need to convert it to a binary number with log(k) digits. right?

Comment: @Prashnant @OliPro007 based on what you said, I think the following will do almost the job: `Integer.toBinaryString(names.indexOf(name))` and then I just need to add enough 0s to have a binary number with log(k) digits. right?

Comment: @Reza Seems like it, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856626/convert-integer-to-zero-padded-binary-string) may help you do that.

Comment: why don't you use stringObject.getBytes(); it returns byte[]

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Why can't *you* write this code?

Comment: @Raedwald just did and posted it here. But I wouldn't have been able to write it (soon) if you guys had not helped me. I don't know if I should delete this question now that I figured it was not a good question, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who helped me with their comments.

```
    public int[] return_binary_encoding(String name, ArrayList<String> names) {

    int code[];
    int domain_size= names.size();
    int siz_of_code= (int)Math.ceil(Math.log(domain_size)/Math.log(2));
    code= new int[siz_of_code];     //it is initialized to 0 by default

    int index= names.indexOf(name);
    String binary_code= Integer.toBinaryString(index);

    //insert binary_code in code from right
    int counter= code.length - 1;
    for(int i= binary_code.length()-1; i>= 0; i--) {
        int digit= Character.getNumericValue(binary_code.charAt(i));
        code[counter]= digit;
        counter --;
    }


    return code;
}
```